# pgf-umlcd: underscore in class name failing

Tags: pgf-umlcd, underscore

I have a simple class diagram drawn with pgf-umlcd, but using an underscore within the class name leads to an error message.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{class}{foo\_bar}{0,0}
    % some stuff here
  \end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The message appears on the `\end{class}` line:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{class}
```

I also tried `\textunderscore` from the underscore package (same result) and `\verb|_|` (which hangs the compilation process).

Is this a bug in pgf-umlcd? Using underscores in attributes and operations works just fine. Is there a workaround or something i am missing?

Comment: I can offer you `\begin{class}{class\string_name}` but it requires `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Unfortunately, the package uses the second argument both for node names and for typesetting, which is a big nuisance; I see no other method than the above: `_` is illegal in printing, whereas `\_` is illegal in node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package uses the argument to `\begin{class}` for two distinct purposes, that is, both for typesetting and for making node names.

When it is used for typesetting, `_` is illegal, whereas `\_` is illegal in a node name.

The simplest workaround is adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and use

```
\begin{class}{Class\string_Name}
```

You can also avoid the (quite ugly) underscore you get with T1 encoded fonts with a more complex workaround, which basically is rewriting the package so that it uses two distinct strings for the two purposes; one has the simple underscores, the other one has them replaced by `\_`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineclassname}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \umlcdClassName { #1 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \umlcdClassNameString \umlcdClassName
  \tl_replace_all:Nfn \umlcdClassName { \char_generate:nn { `_ } { 8 } } { \_\kern1pt }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\xpatchcmd{\classAndInterfaceCommon}
 {\def\umlcdClassName}
 {\defineclassname}
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endclass}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endinterface}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endabstractclass}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endobject}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endclassAndInterfaceCommon}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endclassAndInterfaceCommon}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\xpatchcmd{\endclassAndInterfaceCommon}
 {(\umlcdClassName)}
 {(\umlcdClassNameString)}
 {}{\ddt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}[text width=8cm]{Class_Name}{0,0}
\attribute{name : attribute type}
\attribute{name : attribute type = default value}
\operation{name(parameter list) : type of value returned}
% virtual operation
\operation[0]{name(parameters list) : type of value returned}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. my document is quit short so i will use the simple workaround at first.